# Как прикрутить QScroller к QTabBar'у QTabWidget'а

Tags: android, c++, qt

Необходимо, чтобы в Android приложении, можно было скроллить вкладки. Делается сейчас это так:

```
QScrollerProperties sp;
sp.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::DragVelocitySmoothingFactor, 0.6);
sp.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::MinimumVelocity, 0.0);
sp.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::MaximumVelocity, 0.5);
sp.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::AcceleratingFlickMaximumTime, 0.4);
sp.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::AcceleratingFlickSpeedupFactor, 1.2);
sp.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::SnapPositionRatio, 0.2);
sp.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::MaximumClickThroughVelocity, 0);
sp.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::DragStartDistance, 0.001);
sp.setScrollMetric(QScrollerProperties::MousePressEventDelay, 0.5);
QScroller* scroller = QScroller::scroller(mainTabWidget->tabBar());
scroller->grabGesture(mainTabWidget->tabBar(),  QScroller::LeftMouseButtonGesture);
scroller->setScrollerProperties(sp);
```

Но так не работает, хотя с QTableWidget'ом все замечательно.

Comment: если ебращаться не к tabBar(), а к виджету, то тоже не работает